# Equivalent definitions of an orthonormal function

Tags: integration, functions, orthonormal

I want to prove that the following two definitions for an orthonormal function $\phi$, **in terms of $kT$ time shifts**, are equivalent.

So let $T$ the symbol period and $k$ an integer.

> Definition 1
>
> $
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\phi(t-kT)dt=
> \left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>  1, & if\ k=0 \\
>  0, & if\ k\neq 0 \\
>  \end{array}
> \right.
> $
>
> Definition 2
>
> $
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t-iT)\phi(t-jT)dt=
> \left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>  1, & if\ i=j \\
>  0, & if\ i\neq j \\
>  \end{array}
> \right.
> $

It looks pretty obvious but what could be a proof for this? Setting $k=i-j$ does not seem to produce an equivalent form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a substitution $t = t' + iT$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t-iT)\phi(t-jT)\,\mathrm dt
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t'+iT-iT)\phi(t'+iT-jT)\,\mathrm dt'
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t')\phi(t'-(j-i)T)\,\mathrm dt'$$
Now set $k=j-i$ and rename $t'$ back to $t$.